# How to encode two distinct Unit types using church encoding

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I was studying Haskell and happened to know the church encoding of algebraic data types. For example, the unit type in Haskell can be encoded as a polymorphic function type. But one can also define a `Unit'` type that is isomorphic to `Unit` but essentially treated as a distinct type from `Unit`. Then we have `Unit :: Unit` and `Unit' :: Unit'` as elements from different domains. How to do this in church encoding?

```hs
data Unit = Unit
type UnitChurch = forall x. x -> x

data Unit' = Unit'
type UnitChurch' = ?
```

I tried to search google for questions alike but did not find an answer. My guess is that maybe we can define `UnitChurch'` as:

```hs
type UnitChurch' = forall u. (UnitChurch -> u) -> u
```

which is similar to `newtype` in Haskell.

Comment: You could always add a bunch of non-`x` arguments to the function type. Since they don't provide an `x`, they must be discarded and the only valid function would be `const $ const $ … $ const id`.